# How soon is it OK to ask for a raise at a new job?

Tags: new-job, raise

I started a new permanent job (my previous was contracted) back in the beginning of January, I negotiated a salary that was in between their initial offer and my hourly rate from the contract position. However since I started there have been 4 people who quit from my department (20 people or so max in the department including managers) and only 1 new person has been hired.  As a result my workload has increased over the past few weeks.

I am still in the 90-probationary period (until April 9th) so I want to be careful.  I have received great feedback after my 30-day and 60-day reviews and have even been given a special project by the department director that could make a big impact on department efficiency.

Would it be acceptable to ask for a higher salary at my 90-day review if I provide proof of the workload and accomplishments?

Answer (score 12):

**Yes**, it is appropriate to ask.

Specifically in your case

1. If you can demonstrate the increased workload
2. You can also demonstrate significant accomplishments
3. There has been a rash employees who have left recently

With these factors in mind, you should be able to make a great case.

I would however caution you in terms of your chances due to the fact you have only been there for less than 90 days, *but definitely worth the ask*.  At least 50/50 odds IMHO.

Comment: Most of the people in my position do keep logs of all the work they do.  I'm in a buyer role so I keep track of all the orders I place, as well as any savings I've negotiated. 

I get the feeling that at worst I will be told, "not at this time, but we can have the discussion at your 1-year review".

Comment: IMHO it never hurts to ask when work events happen that can justify your claim..

Comment: I'd agree with @MisterPositive, if you can show your ability, do it and ask. My last couple of jobs I've gotten a compulsory 90 day raise for moving out of the probation period.

Answer (score 6):

After over 20 years as a working professional, I can tell you that there is only one consistent rule with regard to raises: *If you don't ask, you don't get.*

Otherwise it's all relative.  You have to consider the following:

- Are you adding sufficient additional value to the company?
- Is the increase within what that market expects for someone with your job?
- Would it be difficult to hire someone else to do your job?

And most importantly

- Can you easily quit this job and find another?

For example, in my line of work, it could potentially cost an employer $50K (or more) to find someone to replace me, since it takes a new employee about three months to get up to speed.  Knowing this, and knowing the market, I have a good idea how much more I could get if I did negotiate a raise.

Of course you have to know your boss and the overall company culture.  Some times they recognize they're getting a great deal with you and they should pay you more.  Some times you have no choice but to strong arm them by threatening to leave if they don't pay you what you think you're worth.

But as I said, without taking the initiative, you'll never know.  In your particular case I would take the tactic that you're doing a lot more work than you were told you would have to do when you got hired, so you deserve more, and possibly that you feel unappreciated since you've been given more work with no increase in compensation.

They will probably respond something to the effect that everyone is working harder, and you're the only one complaining, so why not be like all the others.  To which you respond that you can't be responsible for anyone else's career choices, only your own.

At the end of the day, one of three things will happen:

1. They will offer a sufficient raise, and you will be happy.
2. They will refuse to give you a raise, and you will accept this and continue to work
3. They will refuse to give you a raise, and you quit.

or you never ask, and you never find out what would have happened.

Comment: One benefit I have is that I have educational and workplace experience with the system that they use (SAP) as well as having come from the exact same position (buyer).  Other than learning a few business-specific processes I was able to jump right in with almost no training.  There is another person on my team that transitioned into the buyer role after being in a different role for 2 years and isn't capable of doing the job as efficiently yet.  

I'm confident that nothing bad will happen if I ask, so I certainly think that it's worth my while.

Comment: @PorkPants  Looking at it optimistically, you might have a manager who understands the value you provide and knows you should get more.  At the very least, if they won't give you an immediate raise, it's not unreasonable to insist on something significant after another 3 months.  But mostly I would consider this good practice in learning that, in business, everything is a negotiation.  Many just accept what they're offered the first time and never haggle.

Comment: DING DING DING -- If you don't ask all you'll ever get is the crappy annual increase.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think you should do this. In general, it's not a good idea to ask for a raise until you've been there at least a year, and asking too early might make you look out-of-touch, or worse, entitled. The fact that you're still in your probationary period makes this even stronger.

I hear that you're getting great feedback, but great feedback at your 30-day and 60-day reviews means "You are learning this job well," not "Wow, you are so awesome that we should pay you more than we agreed three months ago."

An exception to this is if your job changes so substantially that it's really become a different job, and one you'd have negotiated a higher salary for. But it doesn't sound like that's the case here. You're doing the same job; it just got harder. It doesn't make sense to ask for a raise in that case; otherwise should everyone get a raise every busy season? Should they give you a raise now, and then take it away when they hire more people?

It's better to just keep doing a good job, and ask about a raise after a year. If you do well on this project, be sure to bring that up then. And congrats on your new job!

Comment: A year is pretty arbitrary, no? It just sounds like a rule employers hope you believe so they can keep your pay low for an extra half year.

Comment: I can see a year being reasonable. It gives you time to establish yourself on the team, see that you weren't just given an easy out for 90 days and couldn't handle yourself in a true work situation when you're expected to know the system and they start throwing hardball at you, and a year is a nice even amount of time to set for a goal for this. 6 months is as well. I don't think that employers say "Oh, we're gonna screw this guy but good!" as much as people like to think. And people with advice tend to aim for as average an estimate as possible, which is prudent.

Comment: That said, @MissMonicaE, I don't see why asking is a big deal. Most companies expect an employee to push their negotiated price up when they drop out of the probation period because they can more reasonably pinpoint their output-vs-compensation-vs-work ratios. "I know that I have to do X now, which wasn't accounted for when I negotiated Y compensation, so I should bump Y up a little to compensate now that I have hands on with the job"

Comment: @djechlin Maybe it's arbitrary, but my understanding is that it's customary, so not waiting looks out of touch with professional norms (however arbitrary they are in origin).

Comment: @SliderBlackrose Even when the probationary period is so short? (Mine's a year, so it wouldn't make a difference.) I figure that unless X is *way* out of the box, you should just roll it into the flexibility that's expected in most professional jobs ("other duties as assigned").

Comment: I agree with @MissMonicaE. I'd recommend holding off until (just before) your first annual review.

Comment: It surely does have to do with the period. Mine was 90 days at one job and 30 at the other. Both times I knew I had signed on at $X and when I got experienced with how old the software was and how ... let's say "finely balanced" ... it was I knew that $X was about $3000 annual more that I should have asked for, so when it came time for review to leave probation I stated as much and asked for the extra $. Then again, I've always been a risk-taker when I feel I know what I should get. So in that regard, it depends on how much you value the money over the peace of mind?

Comment: I think your suggestion is good general information, but not in this OP's particular case.

Comment: While I agree that a manager might find this unexpected, and I agree with the reasons you give for why a manager might deny such a request, but that's the manager's decision, not the employee's. It's not the employee's role to think of reasons they *shouldn't* get a raise. Much "customary" advice about this is terrible. For example, oftentimes annual reviews are at the end of the year, and, particularly, they are after budgets have already been made. More generally, referencing the time you went above and beyond six months ago isn't as compelling as how you're going above and beyond now.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you were on contract, so your first day as a full-time employee, you were probably doing more actual work than a typical new employee. If you are being paid a comparable salary and the workload has increased compared to the level at that time (you have documentation?), you should have a good reason to ask for a raise.

Consider waiting until the probation period is over. Make sure your positive evaluations are documented. You are going to be made an offer. You are in a much better position to counter-offer, so have a few values in mind and be able to justify each level.

If you know there is going to be a set raise, be prepared to have your documentation about the additional work you're doing. They will say this is "standard" or "company policy" but don't let that end the negotiation. Let them know you feel there is an exception and you think you deserve more.

Someone will probably have to get permission from a higher-up in the company. If they really want to keep you, they'll make the effort. This is why it is so important to fully understand what your immediate supervisor expects from you and their current impression on your work. Otherwise, they won't even bother to ask.